# Have the words 'horsemanshipp' & 'warr' been used so in writing, in the early 16th Century?

Tags: orthography, early-modern-english

I was looking for origin of the word carousel, and I found the following,

> One of the purposes of the Royalle Carouselle, as it was called in a
>   patent application of 1673, was to give "sufficient instruction to all
>   such ingenious young gentleman as desire to learne the art of perfect
>   horsemanshipp with all the usual practices and exercises thereof".

http://www.tes.co.uk/teaching-resource/Around-and-about-the-world-of-carousels-Discovery-series-Discover-fairs-308572/

Also in the following book, [Images and cultures of law in early modern England](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HXDzBd6QUUkC&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=horsemanshipp&source=bl&ots=YiBWeXWrfm&sig=Cd3a83FdJORO3e4ORh_jKYRcm4w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vwMQT7SuAs7MrQfes-SJAg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=horsemanshipp&f=false)

My Question is, have the words horsemanshipp & warr been used in writing with a double p & r consistently? Or is it that the usage reflects the way a person speaks those words ?

Comment: sharp :-) I changed it in the description but forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[A collection of scarce and valuable tracts ...](http://books.google.com/books?id=wM1BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA332&dq=%22warr%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UhgQT4-zEtHyrQe8rL2FAg&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBA)", Sir Walter Scott, Baron John Somers Somers, **1811**, p.332.

> In this conjecture, when France in generall, weary with the **warr** with Spain, passionately desired a peace, and Spain, weakened and exhausted with the **warr** with England, wherein that crown received more prejudice in three ...

(emphasis mine.) Also notice *generall*, with a double ell.

Significant dates from nGram: **c1810**, **c1820**, **c1860**

[image]

Note that "Warr" also appears to be a personal name. So, I did not include 'Warr' with an initial capital in the nGram. nGrams begin from 1800.

Comment: I will closely follow nGram from here on, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary shows that the spelling *warr* is found from the Middle English period until the sixteenth century and *horsemanshippe* (note the final *e*)  is a sixteenth century spelling.

Comment: +1 OED. What did the double `r` signify, if anything?